# awk: substitute character after specific symbol

Tags: bash, awk

Consider a column of a file specifying a date as follows `2006-02-04`. The desired output is `2006-2-4` for all lines containing days and months with a leading zero. How would one accomplish this using the awk command with gsub()?

Will remove the question if this has been answered in another question on the site.

Comment: What are your thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: For example, ```x=substr($1,6,2)``` and then ```gsub(/^0/,"",x)```doesn't do the job.

Comment: It would be hard with `gsub`. Do you have `gensub` ?

Comment: IIRC gensub is a GNU extension, so then you need gawk?

Comment: @stephanmg Yes, so I am asking OP if he has GNU awk.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, GNU awk is available.

Comment: @KamilCuk How would one solve this using ```gensub```?

Comment: While I do not know your motivation to do this, it is generally considered a bad idea to change the date format from an ISO format into something else. In this case, by removing the zeros you will make your dates not string sortable and making any Datestring manipulations difficult. In the YYYY-MM-DD format you know exactly that the first four represent the year, the 6 and 7th character the month and the last two the day. In your format everything depends on the location of the hyphens.

Comment: If you really need to do this, just do `gsub(/-0/,"-",date)` where date is the string with the date.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gensub` to match the string with a backreferences and then substitute with zeros removed. The following is a (stupid) example in plain BEGIN block:

```
awk 'BEGIN { x = "2006-02-04"; 
      x = gensub(/([0-9]{4})-0([0-9])-0([0-9])/, "\\1-\\2-\\3", 1, x); 
      print x 
}' </dev/null
```

will output:

```
2006-2-4
```

If you know that the input format is "exact", well then you can just `substr` it if proper characters are equal to `0`...:

```
awk 'BEGIN { x = "2006-02-04"; 
    if (substr(x, 9, 1) == "0") { x = substr(x, 0, 8) substr(x, 10); } 
    if (substr(x, 6, 1) == "0") { x = substr(x, 0, 5) substr(x, 7); }; 
    print x; 
}' </dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use `gsub`?

```
cat file
Mon 2006-02-04 Green
Tue 2006-02-05 Blue
Wed 2006-02-06 Yellow
Fri 2006-12-22 Brown

awk '{split($2,a,"-");$2=a[1]"-"a[2]+0"-"a[3]+0}1' file
Mon 2006-2-4 Green
Tue 2006-2-5 Blue
Wed 2006-2-6 Yellow
Fri 2006-12-22 Brown
```

Just add `0` to a field and leading `0` goes away.

Comment: What does the trailing 1 do?

Comment: @stephanmg `awk` has a syntax like `some_test { something_in_braces }`. But, if the `{` `}` braces are missing, `awk` prints the line if the test is true. So ex. if you want to filter lines with first column equal to `1`, you could `awk '$1 == 42{print;}'` or just `awk '$1 == 42'`. To print every line you could `awk '1{print}'` or just `awk '{print}'`. But missing braces is printing the whole like, so it's just `awk '1'`. So `1` (or any number different then 0) is a shortcut for `{print}`. The script could be `awk '{.......; print}` or shorter `awk '{.....} 1'`.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Thanks you. I forgot about this subtlety.

Answer (score 0):

How about this awk script? (Put it in a file, e.g. `script.awk`)

```
{
 for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
  gsub(/^0/, "", $(i)); 
  printf $(i)
  if (i != NF) { printf "-" }
 }
}
```

Invoke via: `awk -f script.awk -F "-" <<< "2006-02-04"`

Comment: This presupposes that there is no other data (in particular, no other dashes) before the date.

Comment: @tripleee: Yes, but since the OP says it is a column, I assume it is a "date column". So there shouldn't be any other data before the date string. Maybe the OP can clarify.